# Java class extension

Tags: java, interface, abstract, extends, implements

I'm a bit confused on what Java classes inherit with "extends". I have a class called "Shape", and multiple classes such as box, circle. The box, circle, etc. all have three variables in common. The Shape class is needed to hold a static var to count the number of classes. I also have a vector of Shapes in another class. If I declare a circle class will that correctly fit into a shape vector? I also notice I could do something like this:

```
Shape shape = new Circle();  
ShapeVector.add(shape);
```

I know there are interfaces but can they contain static vars as I need with count and will if the vector is made of an interface will it accept implemented classes?

I have tried with interface, abstract class, etc. but I think there are too many combinations to test and it would take much longer than to ask a question.

Comment: `I think there are too many combinations to test and it would take much longer than to ask a question.` well, it will be more effective to actually do in real than ask a question.

Comment: `shapeVector` can be `Vector<Shape>`. Is that you need?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

you need this:

```
package naishe.so.shapes;

import java.util.Vector;

public abstract class Shapes {
    private static int counter = 0;//Not really required, you could just count vector length
    private static final Vector<Shapes> shapesVector = new Vector<Shapes>();

    public Shapes() {
        counter++;
        shapesVector.add(this);
    }

    public Vector<Shapes> getAllShapes(){
        return shapesVector;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return counter;
    }
}
```